# Son of Suckerfish CSS Menu - Sub menu's not displaying below menu item

Tags: html, css, suckerfish

I have a Son of Suckerfish menu set up, but when I hover over the menu item, the sub menu appears on the left of the screen, rather than directly below the item I hovered over.

eg http://blacktownworkersgroup.worldsecuresystems.com/bwc09/events

When you hover over 'Events' the sub menu is supposed to appear below this item.

It's working correctly in Safari and Chrome, but not in IE7, Firefox 3, Opera.

Comment: Code examples would greatly improve your question. Try to isolate the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

The css shows the block to be using absolute positioning. You will need to set top and left attributes to position it correctly.

Otherwise change it to position:relative; and use float:left; as in [this tutorial on SoS dropdowns](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it up.

The original list items needed to be floated, rather than displayed inline. There may have been other elements affecting it also, but it's fixed now!